# How to cite two different references that have the exact same key

Tags: bibliographies, citing, natbib

I have two papers published by the same author in the same year with similar titles so both of these papers have the same key. I'm unable to reference both papers since .bib will just ignore one of the references. I tried changing the key to 'hull2014improvinga' and 'hull2014improvingb'. However, these new keys caused the in-text citation to come out in the wrong format.

These are the references from the .bib file:

```
@article{hull2014improving,
title={Improving outcomes for people with COPD by developing networks of general practices: 
evaluation of a quality improvement project in east London},
author={Hull, Sally and Mathur, Rohini and Lloyd-Owen, Simon and Round, Thomas and Robson, John},
journal={NPJ primary care respiratory medicine},
volume={24},
number={1},
pages={1--6},
year={2014},
publisher={Nature Publishing Group}
}

@article{hull2014improving,
title={Improving outcomes for patients with type 2 diabetes using general practice networks: a 
quality improvement project in east London},
author={Hull, Sally and Chowdhury, Tahseen A and Mathur, Rohini and Robson, John},
journal={BMJ Qual Saf},
volume={23},
number={2},
pages={171--176},
year={2014},
publisher={BMJ Publishing Group Ltd}
}
```

With these keys, the in-text citations will come out correct but .bib will ignore the second one under a 'repeated error' so I can effectively only use one of the references.

> by Hull et al. (2014) in diabetic patients who found an increase from 10% to 88% in completed care
>   plans from 2009 to 2012, patients achieving a BP 140/80mmHg and cholesterol 4 mmol/L increased from 35.3% to 46.1%. Hull et al. (2014) also confirmed an increase in completed care plans as well a decrease in emergency COPD admissions.

When I change the key to `hull2014improvinga` and `hull2014improvingb`, the bibliography is now correct but the in text citation no longer comes out in Harvard style:

> by Hull, Mathur, Lloyd-Owen, Round & Robson (2014) in diabetic patients who found an increase
>   from 10% to 88% in completed care plans from 2009 to 2012, patients achieving a BP
>   140/80mmHg and cholesterol 4 mmol/L increased from 35.3% to 46.1%. Hull, Chowdhury, Mathur & Robson (2014) also confirmed an increase in completed care plans
>   as well a decrease in emergency COPD admissions

I think these are the relevant parts of my main tex:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside,openright]{memoir}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}

\begin{document}
by \cite{hull2014improving} in diabetic patients who found an increase from 10\% to 88\% in completed 
care plans from 2009 to 2012, patients achieving a BP $\leqslant$140/80mmHg and cholesterol 
$\leqslant$4 mmol/L increased from 35.3\% to 46.1\%. \cite{hull2014improving} ...
\bibliography{references.bib}
\end{document}
```

If anyone could explain where I've gone wrong, I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: Two references *cannot* have the same key, point.

Comment: You *must* use different keys for different entries. The effect you are seeing (Hull, Mathur, Lloyd-Owen, Round & Robson (2014)/Chowdhury, Mathur & Robson (2014) instead of Hull et al. (2014) for both) is caused by `agsm`'s decision to make the list of authors unique. That way the wrong impression that both articles were written by the same set of authors is avoided.

Comment: Completely unrelated to your problem, but still something you should fix: `\bibliography` takes the file name of your `.bib` file *without* the `.bib` extension. So `\bibliography{references.bib}` is wrong and should be `\bibliography{references}`. This does not cause an issue on all systems, but on my system (MikTeX on Win 10) the document will not compile if the `.bib` file extension is included.

Comment: You write: "I have two papers published by the same author". In fact, the two papers do *not* share the exact same set of authors. This is very easy to verify: One piece has 4 authors, and the other has 5. Thus, there is no valid basis all all for your claim that you must somehow use the same key for both entries.

Comment: The change of citations style is to avoid ambiguity. Because the first author is the same, what reference is  ***exactly*** "Hull et al. (2014)"? ... "One to these" is not an acceptable answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for the prompt replies @moewe! I understand why the document lists all the authors now. When I search for the bibtex on google scholar, it gave me the same citation key for both papers, this wasn't something I purposely set it to, strange. Thanks a lot for the extra advice, I've made the changes to my code!

Comment: Thank you too @fran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some comments and observations (some already made by @moewe and @Fran in the comments):

- Distinct entries *must* have distinct keys. No exceptions. None. Zero.

  Incidentally, your claim that "I have two papers *published by the same author* in the same year with similar titles so both of these papers have the same key" [emphasis added] is false on the face of it because the two papers do *not* have the same authors: One has 4 authors, and the other has 5. Thus, I can see no factual basis for your claim that the two entries *must* have the same key. Anyway, as already noted, *all distinct entries must have distinct keys*.
- The `agsm` bibliography style employs the command `\bf` (a Plain-TeX command) to bold-face the volume number in entries of type `@article`. However, `\bf` is deprecated and is not defined by the `memoir` document class. I suggest you add the instruction `\let\bf\bfseries` somewhere in the preamble.
- The `agsm` bibliography style practices "sentence style", i.e., all words except the very first in the `title` field get lower-cased automatically *unless* they are encased in curly braces. You should definitely encase "COPD" and "East London" in curly braces, like this: `{COPD}` and `{East London}".
- Do please change `journal={NPJ primary care respiratory medicine},` to `journal={NPJ Primary Care Respiratory Medicine},`.
- The `agsm` bibliography style is provided by the `harvard` citation management package. As such, it is not entirely compatible with the `natbib` citation management package. (This lack of compatibility shows up especially if the `hyperref` package is loaded as well.) To achieve full compatibility, it's necessary to load the `har2nat` package.

[image]

Neither citation call-out uses an `et al (2014a)` or `et al (2014b)` truncation scheme. This is entirely deliberate: the `agsm` and closely-related `dcu` bibliography styles never apply truncation of this sort unless the entries do have the exact same authors (and publication year). Your claim that using two separate keys makes the citation call-outs "come out in the wrong format" reflects a lack of awareness of a deliberate design choice. If you can't stand this design choice, you shouldn't be using the `agsm` bibliography style to begin with.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside,openright]{memoir}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{references.bib}
@article{hull2014improvinga,
title  ={Improving outcomes for people with {COPD} by developing 
         networks of general practices: Evaluation of a quality 
         improvement project in {East London}},
author ={Hull, Sally and Mathur, Rohini and Lloyd-Owen, Simon and 
         Round, Thomas and Robson, John},
journal={NPJ Primary Care Respiratory Medicine},
volume ={24},
number ={1},
pages  ={1--6},
year   ={2014},
publisher={Nature Publishing Group}
}
@article{hull2014improvingb,
title  ={Improving outcomes for patients with type-2 diabetes using 
         general practice networks: A quality improvement project in 
         {East London}},
author ={Hull, Sally and Chowdhury, Tahseen A. and Mathur, Rohini 
         and Robson, John},
journal={BMJ Qual Saf},
volume ={23},
number ={2},
pages  ={171--176},
year   ={2014},
publisher={BMJ Publishing Group Ltd}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{har2nat}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\let\bf\bfseries % the memoir document class doesn't define '\bf'

\begin{document}
\citet{hull2014improvinga}

\citet{hull2014improvingb}
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply and for correcting the code! I'll make these changes to my references. Out of curiosity, why have you used \citet and not just the usual \cite?

Comment: @MustafaMajeed If you load `natbib` it is recommended to use either `\citet` or `\citep` and not plain `\cite`, because the behaviour of that command depends on the `natbib` 'mode' (`authoryear` or `numbers`) for backwards compatibility reasons. If you consistently use `\citet` and `\citep`, your document is more likely to look reasonable if you change the `natbib` mode. That said, `har2nat` was written explicitly to make `harvard`-style commands available with `natbib` and redefines `\cite` and `\citeyear`, so if you always load that package, `\cite` is fine to use.

Comment: ah great, thank you @moewe